# Why do I have to constantly redownload updates?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

My friend gave me his PS3 game *Injustice: Gods Among Us*, but to play it, we always have to wait like 20 minutes to download updates. Why does only this game do this every time we want to play it? Is this the way is going to be all the time? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don't know this exact issue, but are you sure HDD in your PS3 is OK? Had similar problems on PS2 with broken drive - games using that drive loaded slowly and sometimes crashed. And then HDD died completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not playing online, then you can avoid doing the updates. Either disconnect your PS3 from the internet or press circle when the update screen pops up to cancel the update and proceed straight into the game.

If it is necessary to download the update (because you're playing online or missing characters I presume), then maybe the update is not completely downloading or installing properly. If other people have access to your PS3, perhaps they are deleting the update as a practical joke.

Just to be sure, you are talking about the type of update where the screen goes black with white text? I know that with Injustice, there is a system in place where once the game has started, there will be a second online check (which can take a while) to apply balance changes without requiring a hard update to the game. It's impossible to avoid this, but it can be cancelled if you aren't playing online. I can't check, but it may be possible to play online without doing this check as well, since Netherrealm aren't going to be making daily balance changes.